# On covering a disk by non-overlapping subdisks

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, circle-packing

I posted this question many years ago on math stackexchange but it did not get an answer. It had circulated as a puzzle in graduate school.

A disk $D$ of radius $1$ contains disks $D_i$ ($i \ge 1$) of radius $r_i<1$ with pairwise disjoint interiors. Assuming the $D_i$ "use up" the area of $D$ in the sense that $\sum r_i^2=1,$ show the sum of the *unsquared* radii $\sum r_i$ diverges.

Comment: Compare Section 4 in http://web.math.princeton.edu/sarnak/InternalApollonianPackings09.pdf, where the divergence of $\sum r_i$ is credited to  O. Wesler, “An infinite packing theorem for spheres,” PAMS Vol. 11, pp. 324-326, (1960).

Comment: @JHM Thanks for that link. Gives me a place to look.

Comment: @JHM Now that I looked at it, Wesler's article looks direct enough that I will likely understand it on further study. I'll accept your answer below.

Comment: Very interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proven by [O. Wesler, “An infinite packing theorem for spheres,” PAMS Vol. 11, pp. 324-326, (1960).](https://sci-hub.do/10.2307/2032977)